# CSS to anchor strikethrough word above another word

Tags: html, css

I've got a sentence that has a couple of strike through words in it that the client wants displayed above the word in the line. Sort of like this:

<strike>John</strike>
<strike>James</strike>
Jim is the best around.

The issue is that the strikethrough word is not at the beginning of the sentence, but in the middle of it. So I need a way to position two words above the line that stay anchored to the inline word, no matter how the paragraph wraps.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems kinda under-defined; it doesn’t consider various aspect such as, what if the text breaks into multiple lines? Do you want those words then to overlay text on previous lines, or automatically increase line height to make space, or …?

Anyway, in it’s most simple form it could be something like this:

```css
body { padding-top:5em; }
.delcontainer { position:relative; }
.deletions { position:absolute; bottom:1em; left:0; }
.deletions del { display:block; }
```

```html
<p>Foo bar baz.
  <span class="delcontainer">
    <span class="deletions">
      <del>John</del>
      <del>James</del>
    </span>
    <ins>Jim</ins>
  </span>
is the best around.</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ppq286u/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the poor question, I'm new to coding and Stackoverflow. I had tired googling and searching Stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything regarding how to position strikethrough text in that way. Thanks for helping.